# article moves to K2 Article in Joomla 1.7

Tags: joomla, joomla1.6, joomla1.7

i use Joomla 1.7 and i recently install K2 Extension i want to move my article to K2 article

```
how it is posible ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on k2 dashboard you will get the option to import joomla content.

look at http://yoursite/administrator/index.php?option=com_k2

on top toolbar last button is to import joomla content.

Comment: Then once you have imported your articles, you can turn off the import icon in the K2 parameters.